# Storing data in multiple arrays (bash)

Tags: arrays, bash, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store the contents of a .txt file in two sets of arrays in bash. The file is a list of characteristics for given data files, delimited by vertical bars (|). So far, I have written code that reads the file and prints each line of data separately, each followed by the given sections of the line.

```
#prints line of text and then separated version
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
 words=$(echo $line | tr "|" "\n")
 for tests in $words 
 do 
  echo "> $tests"
 done
done < "$1"
```

Example output:

```
Text read from file: this|is|data|in|a|file
> this
> is
> data
> in
> a
> file
Text read from file: another|example|of|data
> another
> example
> of
> data
```

Is there a way for me to store each individual line of data in one array, and then the broken up parts of it within another? I was thinking this might be possible using a loop, but I am confused by arrays using bash (newbie).

Comment: You might be going about this all wrong - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK -- I just read in the lines like you have done, and append them to the `lines` array.  Then, use `tr` as you have done, and append to the `words` array.  Just use the parentheses to mark them as array elements in the assignments:

```
$ cat data.txt
this|is|data|in|a|file
another|example|of|data

$ cat read_data.sh 
#!/bin/bash
declare -a lines
declare -a words
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
    lines+=( $line )
    words+=( $(echo $line | tr "|" " ") )
done < "$1"

for (( ii=0; ii<${#lines[@]}; ii++ )); do
    echo "Line $ii ${lines[ii]}"
done

for (( ii=0; ii<${#words[@]}; ii++ )); do
    echo "Word $ii ${words[ii]}"
done

$ $ ./read_data.sh data.txt 
Text read from file: this|is|data|in|a|file
Text read from file: another|example|of|data
Line 0 this|is|data|in|a|file
Line 1 another|example|of|data
Word 0 this
Word 1 is
Word 2 data
Word 3 in
Word 4 a
Word 5 file
Word 6 another
Word 7 example
Word 8 of
Word 9 data
```

Comment: You could also do words using bask substitution: words+=( ${line//|/ } )

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I'm having some issues with my data breaking when there is a space between two characteristics (within the same delimeters). For example: |2017-06-20 11:16:39.103| splits into two "Word" and "Line" indexes. Any tips for how to avoid this other than deleting the space between the two characteristics?

Comment: Yes.  Since the field delimiter is a pipe, swap pipes with spaces: `words+=( $(echo $line | tr "| " " |") )`.  Now, the words that had spaces will have pipes.  In the loop that shows the words, add this line to change the pipes back to spaces (per grail's suggestion): `words[ii]="${words[ii]//|/ }"`